# Want to Verify data on Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, kotlin

As I am learning android and making an application in which I have given a limit (ex. 30K) to the virtual credit card of every user and I am verifying that the amount user asked should be less than the given limit but I am verifying that in the application itself after fetching the data from firebase now anyone can reverse the app and set that particular value as whatever he wanted so now I wanted to compare the requested amount should be less than given limit on the firebase how I can do it.

Comment: Have you tried something so far?

Comment: Actually, I found a way, and trying it I am creating a Node server my application interacts with that server and I'll verify data(limit) on that server and that server will interact with my firestore so far I understand this.